# The forgein key has the value NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to design my database tables to get the `route` from the `routes` table depends on the location of the rider and the time must reach the current time. I am facing problem when I inserted some data in all tables then the stop_id in the `routes` and the `arrivalestimes` tables are `NULL`? Is something wrong with the database design?

One stop has many route. One route has many stop. one stop has many arrivaltime.

I appreciate any help.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
    (stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
     name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
     lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, 
     longi double(10,6)NOT NULL) 

  INSERT INTO stops(name,  lat, longi) values
      ('ABC', '63.838039', '18.700440' ),
      ('DEF', '63.840642', '18.701246' ),             
      ('HIG', '63.868863', '18.665438' )

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(arrivaltimes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      arrivaltime time NOT NULL,
      stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )

   INSERT INTO arrivaltimes(weekday, arrivaltime) values
       ('mon-fri', '05:30' ),
       ('mon-fri', '06:07' )

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes
    (routes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     route INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )

  INSERT INTO routes(route) values
     ('1'),
     ('9')
```

Comment: Please get rid of the `stt.execute()` wrappers, and just show the SQL code directly. That would be a lot more readable than what you have now.

Comment: you must explicitly insert value of foreign keys as well other attributes such as route in last sql statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note: FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES do not insert anything on their own.

- A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.
- The FOREIGN KEY constraint prevents invalid data from being inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the values contained in the table it points to.

What's appearing in results is correct. You haven't passed any value for stop_id while inserting records into routes and the arrivalestimes tables.

Changing your insert statements should fix the problem.